# Py2EXE failing to create Executable

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm trying to create an executable for a Python Project I'm working on.

I've been creating executable for a while, and today when I made a minor change to the program and tried to create the executable, it failed.

I'm using the latest version of Python(x,y), with a full installation.
The error I'm getting is:

```
*** copy data files ***
copying ChangeLog -> V:\python\Project\dist\
copying C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run_w.exe -> V:\python\Project\dist\multimodel.exe
Adding python26.dll to V:\python\Project\dist\library.zip
error: Invalid argument
```

I've got Python(x,y) installed on another computer, and it compiled find, but then complained about missing modules.

Any pointers to debugging the problem ?

Comment: Does it run with the normal Python runtime?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, just moved apartments.  Yes it does work with the runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing the project over a network drive?

I encountered this same problem when trying to use py2exe on a virtualbox virtual machine, with the source files located on a "virtualbox shared folder". The error itself, it seems, occurs when read() tries to grab too big a chuck of data on a network drive:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-May/033285.html

And it seems the core problem won't be fixed. The error seemingly starts when the size of the exe file exceeds whatever limit causes this. The workaround for me was simply to copy it to the local drive. After that it worked perfectly.